# Start process automatically at reboot on EC2 linux (CentOS)

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, centos

I want to make sure that a web service starts automatically when my AWS EC2 Linux machine is rebooted.

To start manually the process I need to type the following commands:

```
sudo su
cd /root/notebooks
nohup jupyter notebook &
```

I edited the /etc/rc.local as per below, but the process never starts. Any ideas?

```
#
# This script will be executed *after* all the other init scripts.
# You can put your own initialization stuff in here if you don't
# want to do the full Sys V style init stuff.

sudo su

cd /root/notebooks

nohup jupyter notebook &

touch /var/lock/subsys/local
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering considering Ubuntu OS,
The easiest and the best solution (though with this it will run even when the server is stopping, but that is not an issue here):

1. Go to /etc/init.d
2. Create a bash script (using `vim script` don't give an extension) in that directory and enter the content as follows:

> ```
> sudo su
> cd /root/notebooks
> nohup jupyter notebook &
> ```

Now, within that directory itself, run the following commands:

> ```
> chmod +x script
> update-rc script defaults
> ```

You're done. 
If you're using 16.04 ubuntu, use update-rc.d.

Comment: @Arturo Make the script inside init.d as I told you and then run "chkconfig --level 345 scriptname on"